# Discord.py slash command auto completion

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a discord bot using discord.py, and i was wondering, how could i add autocompletion for a slash command like on this image?[autocompletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCNEZ.png)

Tried the followin from a youtube tutorial, didnt work for me.

```
 async def drink_autocompletion(
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        current: str
    ) -> typing.List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
        data = []
        for drink_choice in ['beer', 'milk', 'tea', 'coffee', 'juice']:
            if current.lower() in drink_choice.lower():
                data.append(app_commands.Choice(name=drink_choice, value=drink_choice))
        return data
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be useful if you could add the code that you've tried to the question. It's hard to help you when you haven't told us what you tried.

Comment: `async def drink_autocompletion(
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        current: str
    ) -> typing.List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
        data = []
        for drink_choice in ['beer', 'milk', 'tea', 'coffee', 'juice']:
            if current.lower() in drink_choice.lower():
                data.append(app_commands.Choice(name=drink_choice, value=drink_choice))
        return data`

Comment: i used this code from a tutorial, but i dont know how to make it show members

Comment: Can you put it in the question so the formatting is easier to see?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the example/screenshot is not an autocomplete, but rather a regular parameter that is type-annotated as `discord.Member`. Discord will automatically start displaying available members for you, you don't have to do anything special other than adding the type annotation.

Have a quick look through the official examples for more info: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py

PS YouTube tutorials are really bad, as they are usually outdated, teach you bad code, and only teach you to do one specific thing instead of helping you understand what's going on. Just read the docs & look at the examples.